# Javascript/React Native looping only update variable to last value

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm working with react native loop to display a section header and data.

My expected output would be like:

> **> Section 0**
>
> data1 data2
>
> **> Section 1**
>
> data1 data2
>
> **> Section 2**
>
> data1 data2

which will loop the section according to the loop number

However, the actual output is like:
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njHbT.png)

It only display the last looping value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, SectionList } from 'react-native';

    export default class Appointment extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                appointmentList: [{
                    index: '',
                    data: ['']
                }]
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {

            let appointmentListItem = {};
            let appointment = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                console.log(i);
                appointmentListItem.index = i;
                appointmentListItem.data = ['data1', 'data2'];
                appointment.push(appointmentListItem);
            }


            this.setState({
                appointmentList: appointment
            });


        }


        render() {
            return (
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <SectionList
                        sections={this.state.appointmentList}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
                        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { index } }) => (
                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                                <Text>{index}</Text>
                            </View>
                        )}
                    />

                </SafeAreaView>
            )
        }
    }
```

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `appointmentListItem` is being instantiated once, then mutated as the for loop iterates. This results in a single object reference being added to the `appointment` list many times, with the most recent mutation applying to all of the referenced objects.

Move the declaration of the variable `appointmentListItem` into the for loop body, like this:

```
    componentDidMount() {

        let appointment = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            const appointmentListItem = {}
            appointmentListItem.index = i;
            appointmentListItem.data = ['data1', 'data2'];
            appointment.push(appointmentListItem);
        }


        this.setState({
            appointmentList: appointment
        });


    }
```

Comment: ohhhhh, thanks a lot. I've been trying to solve this problem for an hour

Comment: `React-native` can be challenging because of the Connected-Device/Simulator/Emulator requirement. Maybe check out `Appium`, which lets you do Test Driven Development with a bit more ease. Another great strategy is to develop High-Order-Components. In HoC, do just the React dependent things, test it in Node/Browser, then enhance your React Native component. The idea is to limit the 'confusing' parts to the smallest component footprint possible.